# Clarification on how to use "thumbs_up" voting gem with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vote-up-buttons

I am attempting to implement the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) voting gem on a Rails 3 app, however the instructions are unclear on the actual implementation. After requiring the gem [**gem 'thumbs_up'**] and after creating and running the appropriate migration [**rails generate thumbs_up && rake db:migrate**] the README explains the following:

> **To cast a vote for a Model you can do the following:**
>   *Shorthand syntax
> voter.vote_for(voteable) # Adds a +1
>   vote
> voter.vote_against(voteable) #
>   Adds a -1 vote
> voter.vote(voteable,
>   vote)  # Adds either a +1 or -1 vote:
>   vote => true (+1), vote => false (-1)
>   voter.vote_exclusively_for(voteable) #
>   Removes any previous votes by that
>   particular voter, and votes for.
>   voter.vote_exclusively_against(voteable) #
>   Removes any previous votes by that
>   particular voter, and votes against.*

I've been assuming that the use of 'voter' and 'voteable' in the README example are stand-ins for objects in the app, but the usage is still nebulous to me.

**A literal example of what my view, controller, and routes.rb file should look like would be a TREMENDOUS help.** I've spent days trying to figure this out!

In my app, I have Users that vote on Posts - of which there are two types - *Events* and *Links*. Posts are called using **<%= render :partial => @posts %>** and each individual post uses as its view "**_event.html.erb**" or "**_link.html.erb**" - depending whether it is an event or a link.

Answer (score 24):

Hopefully I can help you out a bit.

The generators should have created a Vote model for you. This is the model that holds all the votes, but that you interact with indirectly through the methods you've described above.

So, for you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voteable
end
```

That will get you set up with the thumbs_up methods in each of the models.

Then for example, if you have a controller action in PostsController that is linked to from an "up arrow" on your website, you can create a vote for that user for that post.

A view like this:

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post), :method => :post) %>
```

and a routes.rb like this:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post :vote_up
  end
end
```

And finally, in the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey brady8, can there be more than one model that `acts_as_voter` ? For instance, say I have a `User` model, and a `client` model. Can both of them act as a voter and it works fine ?

Comment: @brady8 I am getting the same NoMethod error as mentioned in the answer below. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: This just brings me to an empty template at /posts/:id/vote_up

Comment: @ajbraus, yes, that's how it's coded (render nothing). The vote happens, which is what matters... what you do afterward is up to you and application specific.

Answer (score 1):

Routing Error

> No route matches {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"microposts",
>   :id=>nil}

this is the link I am using and assume this is where the routing isn't being specified correctly. I ran rake routes and there is a route called vote_up_micropost. Is there anything else I should look into. Thank you

here is the link I added

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!',
    vote_up_micropost_path(@microposts),
    :method => :post) %>
```

Comment: Likely your @microposts variable is nil... which is why it's trying to send you to :id => nil.

Comment: Where and how does one set the @microposts variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a continuation of Brady's answer.

Brady had the following code in his view

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post), :method => :post) %>
```

what he means is.. since link_to by default uses `:method => 'get'` & he wanted to update the record using post & not get so he is using `:method => 'post'`

U can use <%= button_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post) %>, because button by default uses `:method => :post`

so the routes should be

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post :vote_up
  end
end
```

here in `post :vote_up` inside the member, its the `method => :post` & not the post controller

but if you are determined to use `link_to` without `:method => :post` something like this

```
<%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post)) %>
```

then your routing should be

```
resources :posts do
   member do
      get :vote_up
   end
end
```

Hope this helps!