# How do I execute a vote using the Rails 3 gem 'thumbs_up'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, voting, voting-system

So I want votes to be triggered using jQuery/AJAX and an image. i.e. I have a thumbs up icon and thumbs down.

I have setup the gem, and ran the rake db:migrate and have everything sorted out.

But I am not sure how to execute a vote in my app.

In my model, I am using one model to `acts_as_voter`, which is my `Client` model. The model that `acts_as_votable` is my `Upload` model. So a client votes up/down an upload. It literally is a thumbs_up, not so much a 'vote' per se, because there is no karma or anything. It is simply a thumbs up/down from each client per upload.

In my view, this is how I would like to execute the vote:

`$("div#upvote img").live("click", compv.comments.upvote);`

How do I use this actually implement an `upvote` action using this Rails 3 gem ?

Edit: If you are interested in seeing what the function `compv.comments.upvote` does in it's current form, you can see it here:

```
    compv.comments.upvote = function(event){
    var uploaderID = compv.comments.getUploadID(event.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploads/'+uploaderID+'/upvote.js',
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
            var uploadElement = $("li[data-upload-id="+uploaderID+"]");
            uploadElement.attr('data-upload-upvote', parseInt(uploadElement.attr('data-upload-upvote'))+1);
            var imgElement = uploadElement.find("div.image-wrapper > img");
            var img_opacity = imgElement.css('opacity');
            if(img_opacity < 1 ) {  
                imgElement.fadeTo(600, 1, function() {
            }); 
            }
            imgElement.removeClass("downvoted");
            imgElement.addClass("upvoted");
        }
    });
};
```

However, I am well aware that this will likely have to change if I am to get this gem working right. That was just my version of trying to do what this gem can do (although, I would much prefer an implementation from this gem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a question of how to build Ajax actions in Rails in general than anything to do with this particular gem.

Referring to the setup here: [Clarification on how to use "thumbs_up" voting gem with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907744/clarification-on-how-to-use-thumbs-up-voting-gem-with-rails-3)

You can set this up in jQuery with something like:

```
$.post('/posts/' + id + '/vote_up', function() {
  alert('success');
})
.error(function() { alert('Vote error.'); });
```

Hopefully that gets you closer.

Comment: That is with `/posts/` is the controller and `/vote_up` is the action right ?

Comment: So should I not make a `Votes Controller` but rather simply add a `vote_up` and `vote_down` action to the controller that the votes will be acted upon ?

Comment: Yup, that's certainly one way to do it. IMO, if you have votes on many different models, then make a unique votes controller. Otherwise, just have vote_up/down as actions on that one controller.

Comment: Thanks. I think this does add some clarity - along with the other answer.

Comment: Hi, this is working for me, but i am not sure how to refresh the view to reflect the changes.