# Routing error (GET instead of POST) with Vote_fu/Thumbs_up gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to use the vote_fu gem and I encounter a problem that other have as well, but I can't solve this with others' solutions..

I don't think the problem is related directly to the gem.. but rather to some wrong route or a missing parameter..

I have a Msg model which I included the `act_as_voteable`.
For the User Model I added `act_as_voter`

In the Msg controller I added

```
def votefor
    @msg= Msg.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_for(@msg)
    redirect_to :back
end
```

In routes:

```
 resources :msgs do
        member do
            post :votefor
        end
    end
```

And to the show of Msg I added

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", votefor_msg_path(@msg), :method => :post %>
```

But when I click on the link created I get

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/msgs/1/votefor"
```

Why does it 'GET' instead of 'POST'? What am I missing?

Comment: If I use Button_to everything works, but it doesn't make sense with the link_to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its very late to answer this question & I mostly think you must have figured it out... I ran into the same issue & I understood the reason why..

This is a sample comment from `routes.rb`

```
  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
```

the `post 'toggle'` here is not the post-controller but `:method => 'post'`

link_to default uses `:method => 'get'` but you can override it using `:method => 'post'`

if u use `link_to` .. in the example without `:method => 'post'`

your routing should be

```
resources :msgs do
   member do
   get :votefor
   end
end
```

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

For the doubt you have:

link_to with a :method => :post

use this

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", votefor_msg_path(@msg), :method => :post %>
```

and in the routes it should be

```
resources :msgs do
       member do
       post :votefor
       end
end
```

the post :votefor .. is :method => :post not the posts controller.

Do check for [brady8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907744/clarification-on-how-to-use-thumbs-up-voting-gem-with-rails-3/9698091#9698091)

Comment: didn't quite understand. How do I use link_to with a POST and not a GET?