# Overriding a model rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, vote-up-buttons

I am trying to override a model of forem gem so that I could use thumbs_up gem for voting purpose.

I did a rails g model Post and trying to inherit the post model of forem by this line of code

```
class Post < Forem::Post

    acts_as_voteable
end
```

same for the controller

```
class PostsController < Forem::Postscontroller

    def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end
  end

end
```

I keep getting this error

> undefined method `vote_up_post_path'

in my route.rb

```
 mount Forem::Engine, :at => "/forums"


resources :posts do
  member do
    post :vote_up
  end
end
```

I guess I am doing something really stupid out here and I am not overriding the model correctly. I was using this [Clarification on how to use "thumbs_up" voting gem with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907744/clarification-on-how-to-use-thumbs-up-voting-gem-with-rails-3) post to set up thumbs_up

Can someone help??

Comment: The path methods are generated from routes.rb. Do you have a route for the vote_up action?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw I have updated the question with routes information please have a look

Comment: Ok, so what do you get when you run rake routes?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw   vote_up_post POST   /posts/:id/vote_up(.:format)    {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"posts"}

Comment: That all looks fine then. Where exactly is the undefined method exception being raised?

Comment: It is raised on this line :---   <%= link_to('vote for this post!', vote_up_post_path(@post), :method => :post) %>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6557/discussion-between-dev-r-and-patrickmcgraw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a stupid mistake, realized it while having discussion with patrickmcgraw.

forem hides your routes and and you have to mention main_app before the routes, so after writing

`main_app.vote_up_post_path` instead of `vote_up_post_path` the page was up again.

Hope it helps someone trying to use forem.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm getting your question correctly, you wanna change the behavior of forem Post in order to support voting using acts_as_votable.
For that to work you need to re-open Forem::Post class in an initializer (e.g. config/initializers/forem.rb) and add to it acts_as_votable line like this:

```
module Forem
  class Post
    acts_as_votable
  end
end
```

And the same for Forem::PostsController:

```
module Forem
  class PostsController
    def vote_up
      begin
        current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
        render :nothing => true, :status => 200
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        render :nothing => true, :status => 404
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: where exactly should I put this code? because if I put it in the initializer i.e config/initializers/forem.rb. My forem paths itself become unrecognizable