# rails voting gem, thumbs_up, with no user. also, routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to use the thumbs_up gem without having users log in? Basically, I want anyone to vote for stuff without having to log in, like http://www.yourather.com .

Lastly, I get a routing error message when I try to to vote on a comment, samething happens when voting on an article.

```
No route matches [GET] "/comments/1/vote_up"
```

Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voteable
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voteable
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("up_arrow.jpeg"), vote_up_comment_path(@comment), 
    :method => 'post' %></br>
<%= link_to image_tag("down_arrow.jpeg"), vote_down_comment_path(@comment), 
    :method => 'post' %></br>
```

Controller:

```
def vote_up
  begin
    vote_for(@comment = Comment.find(params[:id]))
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :nothing => true, :status => 404
  end
end

def vote_down
  begin
    vote_against(@comment = Comment.find(params[:id]))
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :nothing => true, :status => 404
  end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :comments do
  member do
    post :vote_up
    post :vote_down
  end
end

resources :articles do
  member do
    post :vote_up
    post :vote_down
  end
end
```

Rake Routes (relevant part):

```
vote_up_comment   POST    /comments/:id/vote_up(.:format)      comments#vote_up
vote_down_comment POST    /comments/:id/vote_down(.:format)    comments#vote_down
comments          GET     /comments(.:format)                  comments#index
                  POST    /comments(.:format)                  comments#create
new_comment       GET     /comments/new(.:format)              comments#new
edit_comment      GET     /comments/:id/edit(.:format)         comments#edit
comment           GET     /comments/:id(.:format)              comments#show
                  PUT     /comments/:id(.:format)              comments#update
                  DELETE  /comments/:id(.:format)              comments#destroy
vote_up_article   POST    /articles/:id/vote_up(.:format)      articles#vote_up
vote_down_article POST    /articles/:id/vote_down(.:format)    articles#vote_down
articles          GET     /articles(.:format)                  articles#index
                  POST    /articles(.:format)                  articles#create
new_article       GET     /articles/new(.:format)              articles#new
edit_article      GET     /articles/:id/edit(.:format)         articles#edit
article           GET     /articles/:id(.:format)              articles#show
                  PUT     /articles/:id(.:format)              articles#update
                  DELETE  /articles/:id(.:format)              articles#destroy
root                      /                                    voteables#index
                          /comment/:id(.:format)               comments#show
                          /article/:id(.:format)               articles#show
```

I've looked at [Clarification on how to use "thumbs_up" voting gem with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907744/clarification-on-how-to-use-thumbs-up-voting-gem-with-rails-3/9698091#9698091) and other related questions, but I can't make it work.  Thanks

Comment: Try `rake routes` to show what rails is using for your routes.

Comment: added rake routes output (relevant part) to the original question

Comment: can you put the entire `routes.rb` output? this is not the only relevant part since you have duplicate routes defined.

Comment: added more in the original post

Comment: The routing error may be caused by the fact that it redirected to `comment/:id/vote_up` rather than `comments/:id/vote_up`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, it is supposed to be plural ,`comments/:id/vote_up`.  Edited in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs on link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) says that the :method option should be a symbol.  Try changing the view from:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("up_arrow.jpeg"), vote_up_comment_path(@comment), 
:method => 'post' %></br>
```

to

```
<%= link_to image_tag("up_arrow.jpeg"), vote_up_comment_path(@comment), 
:method => :post %></br>
```